# Can tests written in Visual Studio / Selenium / Nunit be made available to non technical QA folks?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, qa-role, nunit

We have a few QA folks that do not code.  I am writing test cases in VS and was asked if there is a way to make them available to them.  Maybe an .exe that lists all the test scenarios and they can pick and chose?  I know about the Selenium IDE but that is not their preferred method.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

"they can pick and chose"

Do you mean to run them?
You can [create a CLI application](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-modern-command-line-applications-in-c-c7bf02c3c64f) that lets they run a command and execute scenarios by tags, or any other categorisation you want.

E.g., if you have a tag for tests related to login, you can run them with a UI like this:

```
myAutomation --tag "@login"
```

Comment: Can you please explain more. I am not familiar with this concept.  Yes, they would need to pick and chose which tests they want to run.

Comment: I've added a link on creating CLIs in C# and a possible UI for your CLI program. The details of the tagging or categories will depend on what tools you use alongside Selenium, but they should be more or less similar,

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at it

Comment: You are welcome. If the you found the answer satisfactory, could you please mark it as accepted, so the community will see it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement nowadays in most professional [automation testing services](https://www.qasource.com/automation-testing-services) organizations where automation test scripts are done by one team and it's batch execution is done by other. There can be **02** possible ways for this requirement -

1. Command Line option - Use NUnit Console Runner to execute your scripts through Command line where you can execute a group of test cases in batch or target based test cases. Few mentioned below documents can be helpful -

> [Official Document](https://docs.nunit.org/2.2.10/consoleCommandLine.html)

> [NUnit GitHub](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line)

Note:- You can also create a batch file of your final NUnit command and share it with your non-technical team.

2. [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) - You can configure your project in Jenkins where you can create schedules for your script execution. Also, Jenkins provide a feature where on completion of scripts, corresponding email will be auto-triggered. In this case manual team has minimum work of just monitoring if job is triggered or not. Here also, you can execute picked test cases as per your requirement.